# UIImageView+AFNetworking and saving images

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, afnetworking

I need to set images to my imageViews. And there are a lot of images (I think it will be near 200mb). I need save it all, for using app locally without internet connection. It's very easy to use category `UIImageView+AFNetworking`, but I don't understand how it save and where?

So in subscribing of methods [here](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.1/Categories/UIImageView+AFNetworking.html)
, you can see that it use a cache policy of `NSURLCacheStorageAllowed`. So images saved in cache folder on disk, right? That's all ok, but what limit of this storage? Do I need to implement next code:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  //another code...
  NSURLCache *URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:4 * 1024 * 1024 
                                                   diskCapacity:200 * 1024 * 1024 
                                                       diskPath:nil];
  [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];
  return YES;
}
```

So `NSURLCacheStorageAllowed` is returned like `storagePolicy` from `NSCachedURLResponse`. So I understand that I mustn't to implement code that I wrote above.

Do all my images will be saved in cache storage locally, if I will using `UIImageView+AFNetworking` category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the same kinda think when i need to show the image in tableView, first i check that image is available locally or not then I download the image and save it like this

```
if (userBasicInfo.userImage == nil) {
            __weak LGMessageBoxCell *weakCell = cell;
            [cell.userImage setImageWithURLRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:userBasicInfo.imageUrl]]
                                  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook-no-user.png"]
                                           success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image){
                                               weakCell.userImage.image = image;
                                               [weakCell setNeedsLayout];

                                               [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
                                                   UserBasicInfo* userBasicInfo = [[UserBasicInfo findByAttribute:@"userId" withValue:@(chatUser) inContext:localContext] objectAtIndex:0];
                                                   userBasicInfo.userImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
                                               } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                                                   NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
                                               }];

                                           }
                                           failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
                                           }];
        } else {
            cell.userImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:userBasicInfo.userImage];
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

UIImageView+AFNetworking, as you've discovered, relies on the foundation URL Loading System to cache data to disk.  The `diskCapacity` will determine how much storage space your app wants at a time.  This will also rely on the server specifying appropriate `Cache-Control` headers when handing you the image - and in some cases, if the cache time is too short, NSURLCache won't store it at all.

For more control over your disk caching on the client side, you could look at [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

SDWebImage has asynchronous image download, with lots of control over caching - which images get cached, for how long, in disk or in memory, etc.  If you need to guarantee that images are stored for a specific amount of time, UIImageView+AFNetworking will probably not give you the control you need, and you should explore this alternative.